# Exponential Moving Average df.ewm() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I am following through step by step of Analytics Vidhya's

Time Series forecasting posted a while ago. I am at the step where we calculate exponential moving average

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/time-series-forecasting-codes-python/?

Link for the article.

Here is vidhya's code :

```
xpwighted_avg = pd.ewma(ts_log, halflife=12)
plt.plot(ts_log)
plt.plot(expwighted_avg, color=‘red’)
```

Mycode:

```
expwavg = a.ewm(span=12, adjust=True).mean()
plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(expwavg, color='red')
```

`a` is my dataset. I believe the function has changed and I am using the most updated one. Any help to solve this function would be helpful.

> error : list object has no attribute ewm or ewma

Thanks,

Comment: what is the type of a? ```print(type(a))```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `a` is not actually a DataFrame. You may want to try this first:

```py
# assuming you have previously done:
# import pandas as pd
adf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(a)
adf.head()
```

If the data appears to be structured as you intend, then your command will likely work:

```py
expwavg = adf.ewm(span=12, adjust=True).mean()
plt.plot(adf)
plt.plot(expwavg, color='red')
```

If this does not work, you will likely need to post some of the code that precedes the three lines you have already posted.